# bootstrap theme align text points in the center of page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working with bootstrap creative theme and I'm trying to make a list of points using md-bootstrap check fa icon.

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

I want to keep the text at the **center of the page** but align the start of the sentences to the left so that both sentences will **start from the same vertical position** and that the fa-check icons will also be aligned.

I tried to do it with ul but I encountered similar problems and the theme didn't style ul tags.

The code I wrote using the creative theme classes:

```html
<div class="text-center">
    <p class="text-muted mb-1 text-center"><i class="fas fa-check text-right"></i> this sentence is longer than the 2nd sentence.</p>
    <p class="text-muted mb-5 text-center"><i class="fas fa-check text-right"></i> this sentence is shorter.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: wrap p tags in another div

Comment: I tried now, it didn't work.

Comment: check the answer, see if it works

Comment: it only worked when i put also d-flex in the p tag classes as well.. let me know if I'm missing something

EDIT: actullay i notice it diminished the space from the check icon between the text

Comment: use `white-space: pre` to preserve the white space between text and icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try aligning with flexbox:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p class="text-muted mb-1 text-center d-flex"><i class="fas fa-check text-right"></i> this sentence is longer than the 2nd sentence.</p>
    <p class="text-muted mb-5 text-center d-flex"><i class="fas fa-check text-right"></i> this sentence is shorter.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```